# QT Plugin Interdependency

Tags: c++, qt, dynamic, plugins

I'm having issues with some of the plugins in my application, I have a main project that loads in a set of plugins such that their dependencies are taken into account. However when I have a plugin that has a dependency on another plugin I seem to be getting some symbolic linkage errors.

**The actual loading of a plugin :**

```
 QPluginLoader pluginLoader(itor->PluginPath);
 QObject *tempPlugin = pluginLoader.instance();
```

**Plugin one (Loaded first):**

```
#include "PluginInterface.h"
class NewWizardPlugin: public PluginInterface
{
Q_OBJECT
Q_PLUGIN_METADATA(IID "Code.PluginInterface" FILE "NewViewPlugin.json")
Q_INTERFACES(PluginInterface)
public:
NewWizardPlugin();

  virtual ~NewWizardPlugin();
};
```

**Plugin Two:**

```
#include "PluginInterface.h"
#include "NewWizardPlugin.h"
class newStandardSubwizard: public PluginInterface
{
Q_OBJECT
Q_PLUGIN_METADATA(IID "Code.PluginInterface" FILE "New_standard_subwizard.json")
Q_INTERFACES(PluginInterface)
public:

  newStandardSubwizard();

  virtual ~newStandardSubwizard();
};
```

The second plugin links against the library for the first plugin

I have some trace in place and know the order they are being loaded in is correct, but using the errorString() function on the QPluginLoader class i know there is a symbolic link error.

Has any one got any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed - I had not updated LLD_LIBARY_PATH to include the directory of the dynamic objects such that the linker could not find them.